# Overwriting executed function in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

In a certain website, the following function is called directly:

```
<div class="entry-meta">
    <?php sparkling_posted_on(); ?>
```

The function is defined thus:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sparkling_posted_on' ) ) :
function sparkling_posted_on() {
$time_string = '<time class="entry-date published" datetime="%1$s">%2$s</time>';
if ( get_the_time( 'U' ) !== get_the_modified_time( 'U' ) ) {
    $time_string .= '<time class="updated" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time>';
}
$time_string = sprintf( $time_string,
    esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_date() ),
    esc_attr( get_the_modified_date( 'c' ) ),
    esc_html( get_the_modified_date() )
);
printf( '<span class="posted-on"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> %1$s</span><span class="byline"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> %2$s</span>',
    sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="bookmark">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        $time_string
    ),
    sprintf( '<span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%1$s">%2$s</a></span>',
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_author() )
    )
); } endif;
```

How can I prevent the function from running, or cause it to return no value, without being able to change the original code (i.e. it’s only possible to add further, external code).

I attempted to use the following, but it doesn’t have any effect:

```
add_filter('sparkling_posted_on', '__return_false', 100);
```

Note: this is taking place on a WordPress website. However the Wordpress SE suggests that questions such as this, which relate to general PHP practices, be posted on SO.

My goal is to essentially prevent this function from showing a blog posts' meta-data (author/date), without being able to control the original code for the theme.

Comment: using a child-theme to override the function?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch it's possible, but the question is still which code needs to be put there. The issue with using a child-theme with this code edited out is (to my understanding) that subsequent theme updates to the PHP files won't apply, since the child-theme PHP override them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see, when the function is defined you have this conditional:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'sparkling_posted_on' ) ) :
```

Which basically says that it'll define the function only if wasn't defined before.

So, basically, you only need to do

```
function sparkling_posted_on() {}
```

somewhere else **before** reaching that point in code, and you'll override the function (and wont do a thing).

I'm assuming the function is defined in the theme's `functions.php`, so to override without touching that code you have two possibilities:

- Create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), and override the function in that theme. (Updates to the parent theme will be applied nonetheless, that's part of the allure of child themes)
- Create a [plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin) to define that function, since plugins are loaded before the theme.

Neither should take much work. Plugin is probably (slightly) simpler.

E.g.: this is a minimum expression plugin that could override the function:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Sparkling Override
Description: Overrides "sparkling_posted_on()", defined in Such Theme
Version:     XP
*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'sparkling_posted_on' ) ) :
  function sparkling_posted_on() {}
endif;
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably, you need to use **remove_action** function.

```
<?php
//put this in your theme's functions.php
//returns @bool
remove_action('init', 'sparkling_posted_on');
?>
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to have any effect.